# Opening project in new tab stopped working in Intellij

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, tabs, ide, macos-big-sur

My current settings in my system :

```
 Mac OS Big Sur :: System preference -> General -> prefer tabs : always
 Intellij :: Preferences -> System settings -> open project : new window
```

Is anyone facing the same issue?

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-213.6461.79, built on December 28, 2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a known problem. Follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284415 for updates.